# Openshift runs my connect(); and disconnect(); functions too late

Tags: json, node.js, sockets, heroku, openshift

I deployed my 7mb app into openshift and heroku. It works fine on heroku but on openshift it takes almost 2 minutes to run my `io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){});` and `socket.on('disconnect', function () {});` functions(Other socket functions run fast enough). This causes huge problems because I use setTimeFout function in my code.

Note: While pushing my files to openshift I used to get

> " openshift failed to execute 'control start' node-modules/bin/express
>   "

error. So I deleted express file at "myapp/node-modules/bin/express" and it worked.

Versions:

ruby: 1.9.3p0

node: 5.3.0

socket.io: 1.3.7

express: 3.0.0

My package.json file for openshift is as following.(I don't have much information about preparing json file so I use default one)

```
{
  "name": "OpenShift-Sample-App",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "OpenShift Sample Application",
  "keywords": [
  "OpenShift",
  "Node.js",
  "application",
  "openshift"
  ],
  "author": {
  "name": "OpenShift",
  "email": "ramr@example.org",
  "url": "http://www.openshift.com/"
 },
 "homepage": "http://www.openshift.com/",
 "repository": {
 "type": "git",
 "url": "https://github.com/openshift/origin-server"
 },

 "engines": {
 "node": ">= 0.6.0",
 "npm": ">= 1.0.0"
 },

"dependencies": {
"express": "~3.4.4"
},
"devDependencies": {},
"bundleDependencies": [],

 "private": true,
 "main": "server.js"
}
```

Thus my actual question is;

**Does openshift normally runs these functions that slow or is it happening because of my mistakes?**

**Edit:** The delay time is decreased from 2 minutes to 14 seconds. Eventhough I didn't change or repush anything.

**Edit2:** The delay time for connection is decreased from 14 seconds to 9 seconds by itself. And the delay time for disconnection still takes 2 minutes. My players have to wait 2 minutes to find out a player is left my game.

Comment: I don't have any problems with those functions on openshift but we cant actually see your code which might be causing the issue

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves Didn't help. My code is working perfectly on heroku. And the only difference between my heroku app and openshift app is my package.json file and ip-port part of the code.

Comment: The comment sir.Thanks though.